# Calling .filter() on a stream looses generic type

Tags: java-stream

I have the following code. "Protectable" is an  interface. My compiler gives the following error: "Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Collection"
When I remove the .filter line, everything works. Why does the compiler loose my type here?
Thanks,
Hannes

```
Collection<Protectable> requiredItems  prefs.getConnectedProtectables(fuzDoc)
.stream()
.filter(protectable -> !protectable.itemVisibleForCurrentUser(fuzDoc))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The variable `prefs` implements `HasConnectedRights` which is implemented as follows:

```
public interface HasConnectedRights {

    public Collection<Protectable> getConnectedProtectables(FuzDocument doc);

}
```

The interface `Protectable` declares the method `itemVisibleForCurrentUser` like this:

```
default public boolean itemVisibleForCurrentUser(Docker<FuzDocument>  doc) {
            User user = UserCtrl.getCurrentUser(doc.getDoc());
            return user == null || itemVisibleFor(user);
}
```

Comment: It may be linked to something in my interface "Protectable" and the method "itemVisibleForCurrentUser" which is a default method. When I replace the type "Protectable" by "String" it works perfectly.

Comment: Please show the signature of `prefs.getConnectedProtectables` method. Also it likely that your `Protectable` interface has the generic argument. How it's declared?

Comment: You are passing the same `fuzDoc` into the different methods `getConnectedProtectables` and `itemVisibleForCurrentUser` which implies that the variable `fuzDoc` must be both `FuzDocument` and `Docker<FuzDocument>` at the same time. That doesn’t look sound…

Comment: No, that should be no problem. The methods expect a `FuzDocument` and we introduced the interface `Docker<FuzDocument>` somewhat later to be able to pass different types of components which all provide a `FuzDocumen`t. `FuzDocument` itself also implements this interface.

Comment: Looks like your are missing an equal after `Collection<Protectable> requiredItems`. Can you please fix the example?